# Sometimes background image for lock screen doesn't show on iPhone

Tags: iphone, screen-lock

I have seen this several times that the image I have for my lockscreen does not show. It is just black with the battery indicator shown in foreground and the unlock slider at bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6 and lower (which was the current version at the time this question was asked), iPhone does not show the background image while the phone is charging. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7, the lock screen background image is shown also when the phone is charging.

So fix for this is to upgrade to iOS7!
<sup>I did the upgrade yesterday...</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If I have a reminder from reminders app that came with the phone that is overdue and is showing up on lock screen can't see the lock screen picture. So when that reminder is finally checked off will see pic again

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -